# Grouping Javascript objects and inserting custom value

Tags: javascript

I have implemented the following

https://jsfiddle.net/f3syta4f/2/

```
function indexByColor (input) {
    var output = {};
    for (var i in input) {
        for (var j in input[i]) {
            var x = input[i][j];
            if (output[x.color] === undefined) output[x.color] = {
                color: x.color, 
                weight: [],
            };  
            output[x.color].weight.push(x.weight);
        };  
    };  
    return Object.keys(output).map(function(c){
            return output[c];
    });     
};
```

**Input**

```
dataSet[0]= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:12,key:0}
   ,{color:"red",weight:15,key,0}
];          
dataSet[1]= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:22,key:1}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:10,key:1}
];
```

**Current Output**

```
an[0]=[{color:"yellow",weight:[12,22]}]
an[1]=[{color:"red",weight:[15]}]
an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:[10]}]
```

However, if data does not exist in that javascript object array, add 0 in it.

**Desired Output**

```
an[0]=[{color:"yellow",weight:[12,22]}]
an[1]=[{color:"red",weight:[15,0]}]
an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:[0,10]}]
```

Further explanation, `data[1]` has `blue` color but `data[0]` does not therefore, `weight=[0,10]`.. `0` comes from `data[0]`, `10` comes from `data[1]`

Comment: why not include the actual code?

Comment: and what have [0,0] at each in default and only update the new value ?

Comment: You'll need to maintain the complete list of colors outside of that for loop, then instead of `j in input[i]` it would be `j in colorlist`; getting `x` then becomes a little more complicated as you'll have to verify that `color` matches before pulling its `weight`.

Comment: I would be glad if you could provide as a answer.

Comment: Please show us the expected output for your jsfiddle. That contains duplicates of the same color within an array and is a very different situation from what you've shown above.

Comment: Please see my updated jsfiddle exactly same input shown above.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Why don't to explain it in the first post and let us to understand what you are actually tryig to do?

Comment: Sorry, I have put all required information as you are currently seeing.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have dataSet object, which has two javascript objects. I sort them based on color information. However, I realized that if I dont insert zero, I could not able to define sorted color comes from data[0] or data[1]. ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
function indexByColor (input) {
    var output = {};
    for (var i in input) {
        for (var j in input[i]) {
            var x = input[i][j];
            output[x.color] = {
                color: x.color, 
                weight: [],
            };  
        };  
    };  
    return Object.keys(output).map(function(c){
        for(var i in input) {
            var weight = 0;
            for(var j in input[i])
                if(input[i][j].color == c) {
                    weight = input[i][j].weight;
                    break;
                }

             output[c].weight.push(weight);
        }

        return output[c];
    });     
};
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3syta4f/4/))

> EDIT: As requested in comments...

The first part only prepares the output object with a union of all colors in the input structure.

Then, inside the map iteration, each 1st level instance is checked for existance of the color, and the weight is either picked or defaulted to 0. That value is then pushed into the weights array.

Comment: @DavidThomas - honestly, I don't see this as being useful, but it's what the OP requested... I simply took his code and "fixed" it to generate the output he wanted